# How would an if statement surrounding a custom field with two variables (holding values) look like?

Tags: php, custom-field

This is from the codex:

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumb', true) ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
        <img class="thumb" src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumb', true) ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I want to include an if statement like the example above. But I can't figure out the proper way of doing that to the following:

```
<?php // Set and display custom field
        $mainbar_left_title = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Mainbar Left Title', true);
        $mainbar_left_image = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Mainbar Left Image', true); ?>
        <div class="float-left">
            <h2><?php echo $mainbar_left_title; ?></h2>
            <img src="<?php echo $mainbar_left_image ?>" alt="" />
        </div> <?php
    ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<?php if ( $mainbar_left_title && $mainbar_left_image ) : ?>`

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 2):

`<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Mainbar Left Title', true) && get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Mainbar Left Image', true) ) ) : ?>
        <div class="float-left">
        <h2><?php echo $mainbar_left_title; ?>
            <img src="" alt="" />
        </div>
<?php endif; ?>`